# Config to set messenger server not taking

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-kafka

I have a Quarkus 3.2 server that I am setting up to send messages to Kafka. I have a working implementation that is verified via unit test using `KafkaCompanion`.

However, when the service is deployed, it does not seem like the configuration to set the address of the server is taking properly; whenever a message is sent to the outgoing channel, I get the following error:

`Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

I also do not see the topics being created on the kafka server.

This is with the following config set:

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.events-outgoing.bootstrap.servers=oqm-infra-kafka:9092
mp.messaging.outgoing.events-outgoing.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.events-outgoing.value.serializer=io.quarkus.kafka.client.serialization.ObjectMapperSerializer
```

I have also added `kafka.bootstrap.servers=oqm-infra-kafka:9092`, with the same result.

Also tried prepending the host in the config with `OUTSIDE://` as that was the config in the tests.

I have verified that the expected config is present in the running process by outputting the value from ConfigProvider.

Messenger code:

```
@Slf4j
@ApplicationScoped
public class HistoryEventNotificationService {
    
    public static final String INTERNAL_EVENT_CHANNEL = "events-internal";
    public static final String OUTGOING_EVENT_CHANNEL = "events-outgoing";
    public static final String ALL_EVENT_TOPIC = "all-events";
    
    @Inject
    @Broadcast
    @Channel(INTERNAL_EVENT_CHANNEL)
    @OnOverflow(value = OnOverflow.Strategy.DROP)//TODO:: this better https://quarkus.io/version/3.2/guides/kafka#sending-messages-with-emitter
    Emitter<EventNotificationWrapper> internalEventEmitter;
    
    @Inject
    @Broadcast
    @Channel(OUTGOING_EVENT_CHANNEL)
    @OnOverflow(value = OnOverflow.Strategy.DROP)
    Emitter<ObjectHistoryEvent> outgoingEventEmitter;
    
    /**
     * Don't call this directly, use the other one
     */
    @WithSpan
    @Incoming(INTERNAL_EVENT_CHANNEL)
    void sendEventOutgoing(EventNotificationWrapper notificationWrapper) {
        log.info("Sending event to external channels: {}/{}", notificationWrapper.getClass().getSimpleName(), notificationWrapper.getEvent().getId());
//      log.info("Kafka server config: {}", ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("mp.messaging.outgoing.events-outgoing.bootstrap.servers", String.class));
        try {
            this.outgoingEventEmitter.send(
                Message.of(
                    notificationWrapper.getEvent()
                ).addMetadata(
                    OutgoingKafkaRecordMetadata.<String>builder()
                        .withTopic(notificationWrapper.getObjectName() + "-" + notificationWrapper.getEvent().getType())
                        .build()
                ));
            this.outgoingEventEmitter.send(
                Message.of(
                    notificationWrapper.getEvent()
                ).addMetadata(
                    OutgoingKafkaRecordMetadata.<String>builder()
                        .withTopic(ALL_EVENT_TOPIC)
                        .build()
                ));
            log.debug("Sent event to external channels: {}/{}", notificationWrapper.getClass().getSimpleName(), notificationWrapper.getEvent().getId());
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            log.error("FAILED to send event to external channels: {}/{}:", notificationWrapper.getClass().getSimpleName(), notificationWrapper.getEvent().getId(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
    
    public void sendEvent(Class<?> objectClass, ObjectHistoryEvent event) {
        this.sendEvents(objectClass, event);
    }
    
    public void sendEvents(Class<?> objectClass, ObjectHistoryEvent... events) {
        this.sendEvents(objectClass, Arrays.asList(events));
    }
    
    public void sendEvents(Class<?> objectClass, Collection<ObjectHistoryEvent> events) {
        for (ObjectHistoryEvent event : events) {
            log.info("Sending event to internal channel: {}/{}", objectClass.getSimpleName(), event.getId());
            if (event.getId() == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Null ID for " + event.getType() + " event given for object of type " + objectClass.getSimpleName());
            }
            this.internalEventEmitter.send(new EventNotificationWrapper(objectClass.getSimpleName(), event));
        }
    }
    
}
```

What can I do to make Quarkus recognize the server config?

Edit: Interestingly, I found this snippet of log during the init process:

`SRMSG18258: Kafka producer kafka-producer-events-outgoing, connected to Kafka brokers 'OUTSIDE://oqm-infra-kafka:9092', is configured to write records to 'events-outgoing'`

This indicates that the config is in fact being picked up, but somehow when the connection is made, it goes back to trying to connect to localhost?